# PRISMA: How to receive REST API post requests (non GraphQL)?

Tags: rest, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

How to create one route for receiving non graphql post requests?

I have my graphql server, and want to receive some non graphql data on it.

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({ ... })

server.express.get('/route', async (req, res, done) => {
  const params = req.body;
  // do some actions with ctx..
})
```

How can we access to `ctx.db.query` or `ctx.db.mutation` from this route?
Thanks!

Related question: https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga/issues/482
https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/how-to-create-one-route-for-receiving-rest-api-post-requests/7239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same variable you passed in the context:

```
const { prisma } = require('./generated/prisma-client')
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: {
    prisma,
  },
})

server.express.get('/route', async (req, res, done) => {
  const params = req.body;
  const user = prisma.user({where: {id: params.id} })

  res.send(user)
})
```